# Http requests overriding activity start up - Android

Tags: android, http, android-activity, dialog, httpwebrequest

Hey,
I've come across a strange problem. I'm trying to launch an activity that goes straight to a progress dialog launch and then makes a http request with logs the user into various sites. The code in onCreate() is something like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.upload);
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Login", "Attempting to login now...", true);//the login progress dialog
executeUpload();
```

However, when I run this, the screen goes blank and delays launch of the activity until exuteUpload() completes. I'm a bit stumped. Has anyone some across a similar problem or have any suggestions as to what could be causing this?

ExecuteUpload is simple enough:

```
state = new O2State();//for the O2 site
state.logon();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State.login is probably not running in another Thread. This will cause the UI thread to seemingly stop.

This is likely candidate for using AsyncTask.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Also an AsyncTask tutorial
http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/rotating-async-tasks/

Comment: hey, definately sounds like thats the problem. But looking at the links you gave me, it looks like I might have to totally change the state classes? Is there a way of simply wrapping the state.logon call somehow so that it executes concurrently, without totally ripping my code apart an starting from scratch?